# Is differentiability the same as continuity of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I've seen an answer or two on this, but they don't fully make sense with me. One example is that $sin\frac{1}{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but then isn't the derivative: $$-\frac{cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$$

This is not continuous at $x=0$ as well. Can someone explain this, or give an example of when the differentiability of a function is not the same as the continuity of the derivative?

Comment: How can you talk about continuity of the derivative at a point where the derivative is not defined?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That's why I got confused. I saw that on another post and it didn't make sense. Do you know of any cases that the differentiability of a function is not the same as the continuity of the derivative?

Comment: That derivative is continuous everywhere it is defined. A function is (quite tautologically) differentiable at a point precisely when the derivative is defined at that point. I think the real question you have is "what kinds of discontinuities can derivatives have?" A partial answer due to Darboux is that derivatives have the intermediate value property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider the function given by
\begin{align*}
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & \text{if} \ \ x \neq 0,\\\\
0, & \text{if} \ \ x = 0 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Such function is differentiable at $x = 0$, but its derivative is not continuous at this point.

Indeed, one has that
\begin{align*}
f'(0) & = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) - \cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right), & \text{if} \ \ x \neq 0,\\\\
0, & \text{if} \ \ x = 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

which confirms our claim.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: We have presented the same example.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, indeed. Is there something we should do about it?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, thank you!

Comment: @Caedmon You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Comment: I'll delete mine.